# Show/hide context menu item based on the selected row data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have a context menu and on right click the menu shows up, context menu show when the user right clicks on the table row.

On the row I have a column which has the status of the current row to show it is locked or not. If the row is locked I want to hide certain context menu items so here I am using this code but I don't know how to get to the row the right click happened.

```
$('.menu').contextMenu(menu1, {
            beforeShow: function () {
                var lock = $("#table tr");

                if ($("table input[name='checked']:checked").length > 1) {
                    var i = 0;
                    $(this.menu).find('.context-menu-item').each(function () {
                        i = i + 1;
                        if (i == 1 || i == 7 || i == 8) { $(this).hide(); }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var i = 0;`enter code here`
                    $(this.menu).find('.context-menu-item').each(function () {
                        i = i + 1;
                        if (i == 1 || i == 7 || i == 8) { $(this).show(); }
                    });
```

For multiple checked item the menu hits if condition with certain items (there are 8 items in contextmenu)
and I'm trying to get the selected row data attribute which I defined inside the html. 
How to find the row on which this right click occured:

```
<tr class="menu page-datagrid-text" data-lock ="@item.isLocked.ToString()">
```

Comment: Can you link to the site you got this plugin from? there are so many...

Comment: This is JQuery Context menu plugin

Comment: There are 500 different plugins, *500*. I can't possibly go through everyone to find the documentation, to see if any arguments are supplied. Link to the page.

Comment: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/